# Searching in a compressed(.gz) file using java

Tags: java

We have large files where in we need to do pattern searches. Looks like when we use GZIPInputStream it uncompress the file in memory and then i need to do search on it. In memory one uncompressed file as example taking 600MB and we get 10 at least requests to our server and we can not afford searching of 2 or 3GB files in memory search. What we are looking for is do we have a way to uncompress line by line and do the search? (or) any other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

ZLib supports partial and sequential decompression, so you can read in a part of the gzip file (but remember gzip files have a header) and call util.zip.Inflater with the number of bytes you want to inflate from.

Note in particular the method

```
setInput(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

that lets you start at off bytes into the gzip file and read in and decompress len bytes from that point.

Javadoc is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html